# Way too much lemon in my basting liquid

Tags: pork, lemon, greek-cuisine

Let me start by saying, I am a good home cook.
I have been cooking for a while with positive review.

I decided to try something I had never done before.  I made a Greek Inspired Pork Roulade.  It required making a filling with spinach, cream cheese, feta, kalamata olives, artichoke hearts, lemon zest, and garlic.
I tasted the filling and it was great.  I pounded the pork to about 1/4 inch thin and spread the filling and rolled it into a Roulade.  I didn't have twine so I rolled it in parchment paper.  The final step was to baste the Roulade with mustard, lemon juice, garlic, and oregano sauce.
So, after baked it for 15 -20 minutes, I basted. Everything looked and smelled amazing, but looks and smells can be deceiving...it wasn't great!!
But, neither myself or my husband could finish it due to the tartness.

Can anyone give me tips on how to fix this...I hate wasting food but can't seem to be able to figure this one out.

Comment: @elbrant please don't leave answers as comments. They bypass all of our quality criteria and make it more difficult on everybody to know where to look for each kind of information. If your goal is to say something about a solution to the question, write it up as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

It won't look as nice, but it should be possible to rescue the flavour.

As you've also got lemon in the filling, and feta is quite tart as well, I suggest you first remove the filling and dilute with extra cream cheese (and possibly olives and cooked garlic). Reheat enough  to have with the pork and chill the rest too have with something else within a couple of days.

Wipe the meat with kitchen roll (paper towel) while the filling is removed. If you're desperate you could even quickly rinse it (in boiling water if hot, chilled water if cold).

Then reroll and reheat, or serve deconstructed.

Answer (score 1):

My initial thoughts would be:

- Sprinkle sugar over the dish, or blend it into the sauce.
- If the Roulade is sitting in the sauce, you might consider removing
  it and making the sauce fresh/over with less lemon juice.
- Another alternative might be adding more of the other sauce
  ingredients. That should dilute the extra lemon juice to the right proportion.